# Use conditional rendering in React but a variable storing the element is not defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a small forum that conditionally renders some buttons, but I could not get it to work since a variable is always 'undefined'

```
function NewExpense(props) {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);

  const startEditingHandler = () => {
    setIsEditing(true);
  };
  
  const saveExpenseDataHandler = (enteredExpenseData) => {
    const expenseData = {
      ...enteredExpenseData,
      id: Math.random().toString(),
    };
    
    props.onAddExpense(expenseData);

//showedElement is not defined in the return statement??
    let showedElement = isEditing ? (
      <ExpenseForm onSaveExpenseData={saveExpenseDataHandler}></ExpenseForm>
    ) : (
      <button onClick={startEditingHandler}>Add New Expense</button>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="new-expense">
   //showedElement is not defined
      {showedElement}
    </div>
  );
}
```

What did I do wrong? I made a variable and conditionally set its value to the rendered element, but React kept yelling at me that it was not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you define a local scope variable `showedElement` in `saveExpenseDataHandler`?

Because its scope is local (local inside function), it's always `undefined`.

It's enough to add it in `return` function.

Check the following code.

```
function NewExpense(props) {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);

  const startEditingHandler = () => {
    setIsEditing(true);
  };

  const saveExpenseDataHandler = (enteredExpenseData) => {
    const expenseData = {
      ...enteredExpenseData,
      id: Math.random().toString(),
    };

    props.onAddExpense(expenseData);
  };

  return (
    <div className="new-expense">
      {isEditing ? (
        <ExpenseForm onSaveExpenseData={saveExpenseDataHandler}></ExpenseForm>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={startEditingHandler}>Add New Expense</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, if you don't want to include this condition explicitly in the component return, you could define a method like this.

```
function NewExpense(props) {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);

  const startEditingHandler = () => {
    setIsEditing(true);
  };
  
  const saveExpenseDataHandler = (enteredExpenseData) => {
    const expenseData = {
      ...enteredExpenseData,
      id: Math.random().toString(),
    };
    
    props.onAddExpense(expenseData);

    const showedElement = () => {
      if (isEditing) {
        return <ExpenseForm onSaveExpenseData={saveExpenseDataHandler}></ExpenseForm>;
      }
      return <button onClick={startEditingHandler}>Add New Expense</button>;
  };

  return (
    <div className="new-expense">
      {showedElement()}
    </div>
  );
}
```